# What is the rotation that gives an horizontal flip and a vertical flip?

Tags: algorithm, math, rotation, degrees

Given this unit circle (degrees):

[image]

What would be the code for functions that would rotate the image to flip it horizontally and vertically?

For example,

- FlipHorizontal(315) = 225,
- FlipHorizontal(45) = 135,
- FlipVertical(315) = 45,
- FlipVertical(135) = 225.

Comment: What programming language? Or do you want pseudo code?

Comment: C like pseudo code would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

add 180, modulo 360.  so add 180 and subtract 360 if it's greater than 360.

```
angle += 180;
if (angle > 360) angle -= 360;
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

if you want to FlipHorizontal(315) = 225, you need to do something like this:

1) alpha > Pi?

2) if yes, you transformation will be 2Pi - alpha -> Pi + alpha, where 2Pi - alpha = 315.

3) if no, you transformation will be alpha -> Pi - alpha, where alpha = 45.

Solve this task like maths' task

Comment: `input alpha;`
`if alpha>Pi then 
        do  {var1 = 2*Pi - alpha; alpha = var1 + Pi;}
else     
        do  {var1 = Pi - alpha; alpha = var1; }`
it's not the best code, but i think it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
vflip(a)
{
  return 360-a;
}

hflip(a)
{
  if (a > 180)
    return 540 - a;
  else
    return 180 - a;
}

flipboth(a)
{
  return 360 - ((a>180)?540 - a:180 - a);
  //aka
  //return vflip(hflip(a));
}
```